# Image processing with programming

Tags: image-processing

I was given a task to process image files, and analyze data on them.
Imagine an exam paper with A, B, C, D answers to fill in (Picture1).
[image]
A vision sensor inspects this paper, and saves an image file of it on the computer. I would like to have this image file analyzed (check for the correct filled in circles) and create a document with the results. 
With close to no programming skills, I am kind of clueless on how to even start this project. I basically need something to detect if the red circles are filled in or at least have some % of the area filled (Picture2), and the others in the row are not, and give scores accordingly.
[image]

Comment: "With close to no programming skills": Sorry, that question is too broad.

Comment: At least pick a programming language, or mention the system on which it needs to run. Is this Windows? Linux? Web-based?

Comment: You are going to have lots of problems without any programming knowledge. You need to think about image orientation (whether the scans are skewed, rotated or flipped). You need to think about whether the size matches your template size. You need to think about noise in the scan and variations in colour. You need to also consider whether the student has just filled in all circles and that means you will accidentally award full marks. You will need to think about what the output is - do you have to recognise a student name or will you create new images with the score drawn on?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know that this could help you and I even do not know that is the right answer but I can not make comments yet.

So basically you should make some application where you can process every picture and check pixels in some area that covers your template with good answers. Then you store that there was true/false result in inspection and sum this up to store the score.

Maybe this will be helpful: [Images and Pixels by Daniel Shiffman](https://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/)

But also I think that with no programming skills this could be very hard to accomplish your task.

Comment: What language is that, though? It's not really clear from the page.

Comment: @Nyerguds, it's Processing language (and IDE itself),

[Wikipedia -> Processing (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language))